# JHipster - Creating server and client part separately

Tags: jhipster

would like to create backend and frontend separately.

Creation can be done with "jhipster --skip-client" and "jhipster --skip-server".

But in case of the frontend (--skip-server) "--db" and "--auth" have to be specified.
In case of using MS SQL Server as the database (dev and prod) and JWT for authentication, how does the command has to look like?

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

The Command you're looking for is

```
jhipster --skip-server --auth=jwt --db=sql
```